Why does this spring not affect the acceleration of blocks?
Why does the spring not affect the acceleration of blocks? Why are they same? (Consider spring and string to be massless.)


The tension in the string is proportional to $M_2 g - M_1 g$. There would be tension in the string even without the spring. The presence of the spring does not alter the tension in the string. It just provides a means of measuring the tension in the string, by measuring the extension of the spring.
I am assuming the spring is in equilibrium. If the weights were initially supported so the spring is initially relaxed, the spring would stretch when the weights are first released and this would change the dynamics of the situation, but when equilibrium is reached the spring does not affect the opposing forces of the weights.
